# ant uninstall android package

Tags: java, android, ant, android-manifest

is it possible to uninstall apps from a connected device using ant, without being in the project with the same package name on the computer?

The reason being that I have an ant build script which changes the name of the package (and icons) so the device connected will have many apps on it that I would otherwise have to find and uninstall one by one on the device.

ant uninstall seems to only uninstall one package based on the current manifest name, I can't target a file on the device it seems, without further insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to your ANT script and it will uninstall a packaged. You may want to add additional target for this.

```
 <exec executable="adb">
    <arg value="uninstall"/>
    <arg value="<packageName>"/>
  </exec>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that you cannot query packages on a device via ADB. You can only directly target files. If you change the package name, then your script should be smart enough to be able to uninstall it as well. Since you are infact executing this process in Ant.

Why not try setting a flag after you have changed the package name, and then implement some logic to uninstall the new package name, not just the package name that was passed in. This is assuming that you can figure out a way to derive the new name from the old name. Or some consistent pattern.